# Website elements and fonts are too small in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have just finished designing and coding my new project. But I need it to work well in mobiles. I resized my screen to something like 350~400px width and started coding and adding some media-queries to it. Looks great in redimensioned browsers. I have cut some elements and features and everything was fine... until I tested it with my smartphone

The screen isn't big. Less than 4' (probably 3.5). I put some alerts in the code and realised its width was 980px. Almost 3 times bigger than my tests on resized browsers.

Everything is just too small. Other things are great: media queries are working, the cuts I made in the code are OK too, but you can barely see the content in my mobile. This is certainly not I wanted.

I want it to look like an **App** and indeed it looks like an app on the redimensioned browser.

How do you create your responsive websites to deal with problems like this one?

I read something about using **EM** (and there is something new called REM) units but I am still very confused about it. Do I have to change ALL the `px` to `em`?

And also I know you can set the `font-size` in the `html` or `body` tags and all the other elements will inherit from them. Is that an approach? What do you usually do? Is there a trick or something? I'm not using bootstrap nor any other front-end framework.

Comment: applying font-size to your body using media query is a good approach.

Comment: you mean font-size combined with `em` units?

Comment: apply font-size in percentage for your body

Comment: but what about the widths and heights of the other elements?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can try adding the `viewport` `<meta>` tag :

```xml
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

- [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: will chrome understand viewport? how does it work in desktop browsers? do they ignore it?

Comment: The mobile browser should know how to interpret the meta tag(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Comment: ive made a try and it worked. i'm just having some problems with scrolls (on x-axis)

Comment: This solution makes my images more blurry. It would be nice to have a solution that retains the image sharpness that I have without this meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries ([Link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries)) and percentages (%), 16px (default font size) = 100%. I hope it helps.

Comment: `html {font-size:16px;}` is the defacto standard, but is not guaranteed to be true and can be overridden by user style sheets.