# why css font size change when using display: flex;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble with my font size using CSS & HTML. Whether I use relative or absolute size units, it displays my "p" tags (all except bolds in photo) with different sizes when I use display: flex.

If I comment out the flex styles, all p tags get back to the same size, but my layout won't get the de style I want. (I know, it isn't fixed at all right now, but I just started this).

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 550;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

h3 {
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

p {
  font-weight: 407;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  text-align: left;
}

#PruebasCover {
  background-color: rgba(170, 208, 198, 0.24);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#PruebasCover h1,
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0vw 0vw 0vw 0vw;
}

#PruebasCover h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

#PruebasCoverContainer {
  padding: 15vh 0vh 5vh 0vh;
}

#PruebasCoverBotonesContainer {
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 5vh 10vw 5vh 10vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.arrow {
  width: 10vw;
}

.EmptyButton,
.Button {
  padding: 18px 40px;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.EmptyButton {
  border: 2px rgb(0, 163, 163) solid;
  color: rgb(0, 163, 163);
}

.Button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 163, 163);
  border: 2px rgb(0, 163, 163) solid;
  color: white;
}

#QuienesSomos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

#nosotrosNumsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nosotrosNums {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nosotrosNums p,
h2 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nosIcon {
  width: 10vw;
  margin-right: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<section id="PruebasCover">
  <div id="PruebasCoverContainer">
    <h1>Pruebas Para <br> Covid-19</h1>
    <p>Certificadas por la <b>COFEPRIS</b>, <b>INDRE</b> y <b>FDA</b></p>
    <p>
      - Cualitativas (GENRUI y Abbott) <br> - Cuantitativas (IChroma) <br> - PCR <br> - Antígeno
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="PruebasCoverBotonesContainer">
    <a href="#" class="Button">Contacto</a>
    <a href="#" class="EmptyButton">Ver más</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="QuienesSomos">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/77/82/3f/77823f938e6a246ab82fc1207c27908b.jpg">
  <img src="SVG/Arrow.svg" class="arrow">
  <div>
    <h2>
      ¿Quienes Somos?
    </h2>
    <p>
      Somos una empresa mexicana líder en el sector salud y distribución de insumos médicos, conformada por un equipo multidisciplinario especializados en brindar atención médica personalizada y asesoramiento corporativo.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="EmptyButton"> Leer más </a>
    <div id="nosotrosNumsContainer">
      <div class="nosotrosNums">
        <img src="SVG/Dropper.svg" class="nosIcon">
        <div>
          <h2>400+</h2>
          <p>Clientes</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nosotrosNums">
        <img src="SVG/Doctor.svg" class="nosIcon">
        <div>
          <h2>20+</h2>
          <p>Médicos Especialistas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Result: Displayed screen, all texts are "p" tags, even though they have all different sizes

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a minimal reproducible example, so that we can help you better.

Comment: In the span tag you put the p and h tags. This is not valid for html.

Comment: @Simplicius Done, thanks for the suggest, Im just new at this.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I just tried that, nothing changed, though my html might be cleaner now. thank you

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but advice.

Answer (score 2):

ok, so this might be unrelated, but I had the same issue.
Fact is, I was writing the HTML page from scratch. I set up my CSS base rules and they broke within the flex elements for mobile devices.
I believe this is similar to what Ethan is asking here.

In my case, since I had written my HTML from scratch, I had forgotten the `viewport` meta tag in the `head` HTML tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Found my answer in this question: [Website elements and fonts are too small in mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855154/website-elements-and-fonts-are-too-small-in-mobile-devices)

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you are using here [vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units). so if you want to fix your font-size use [px](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: As mentioned in description, it does not matter if I use px, vw, %, em, rem, etc... Font size changes when I display flex onto a container

Comment: yeah, you are right, but flex also use for to fit content inside container or make dynamic font size, so why your using this ? what's your goal here ?

Comment: I want that font to be just the same size than outer fonts (except buttons and bold tittles) because they are supposed to hace just the same font size value. I use flexbox in order to achieve that arrangement (left icon and two different right texts in that case)

Comment: check this 
https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmanii/qLufd08z/2/
it's working when i change it to px

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you posted, then removed all `flex`-related properties. Other than the expected layout flow changes, there is no difference in text size. All instances of `p` use the same 16px size. Have you posted all your styles? Your image shows sans-serif font, but your styles don't contain `font-family`, so normally the font would default to a serif font on most browsers/OSs. If you have more styles or are using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, please update your question to specify that.

As another thought, when I scale the window, I see the expected scaling in most of the text because you are using `vw`-relative font sizes. The normal paragraph text is the only text that does *not* scale. Perhaps this is what you are seeing? Try changing:

```css
p {
  font-weight: 407;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```

to:

```css
p {
  font-weight: 400 /* 407 is not a font-weight value */;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 3vw; /* use vw-relative units to match other text elements on the page */
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```